# cant make button float: right;

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make my button go to the right side of the div, and when the div is resized it moves with the div so it stays on the edge of the right side of the div.

I've tried using `style=float: right;` but that doesn't seem to be working.. could anyone help me out here?

here's my code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4esgwdkt/3/)

Comment: I'd recommend abstaining from using inline CSS since you already have it in it's separate file. Try using flexbox like the other answer recommended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using flexbox, you can do it like this

```
#drag {
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    background: blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    display: flex;

    flex-direction: row; /* <--- Makes sure it's a row */
    justify-content: space-between; /* <--- Makes the space */
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/4esgwdkt/16/)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can align P tag to the right by

```
margin-left: auto;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4esgwdkt/41/

Your float: right not working, because you use display: flex;

Answer (score 1):

You can use this demo:

Modified your answer:
https://jsfiddle.net/4esgwdkt/46/ `DEMO`

if anything needed then please add comment.